# Woocommerce - Switching Price for Category

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, css

I am looking for the function to change position the price for the category. (I attached an image).
Ok, is not a switch is a remove and add.

¿Where i can find a good explanation about the php function and the list of it?,will be awesome if somebody know a good explanation of the structure too.

Because Codex from [Woocommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-codex/) and [Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/) there isn't all of it.

[image]

Thanks in advanced!!

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Position can be handle by css. You didn't mentioned where you want to move the price woo commerce use different hooks move things around so be specific.

Comment: uhh sorry, yes, i would like to put the price where is the "Fall" in the image.

Answer (score 0):

Add following style to your main stylesheet, make sure this will override all your styles, I prefer add this to the theme header

```
.site-main ul.products.columns-3 li.product{position:relative;}
```

this peace responsible for the price

```
.price{position: absolute;top:0px;left:0px;}
```

adjust left and top values to fit your design, this is good if your "fall" word is static. If you have a public URL for site share it to give a specific class fit to your theme.

Comment: thanks for your help, but doesn't work.
http://brigadafight.cl/divided-store/

Comment: you may need refer to woocommerce template override, basically what you need to do is copy 'template' directory from plugin/woocommerce and paste inside your theme folder and rename it as woocommerce, that way you can modify the templates with modifying the core files, the section you want to changes in directory called 'loop' inside templates.

Comment: Thanks Roshan for your help, I received help from another source!, is fixed!